# Issue with copying the public Key

Tags: centos, ssh, key-authentication

I'm trying to copy the public key to my remote host but I keep getting this message, "Permission denied (public key).

[image]

Password authentication is set to YES in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, I have started again from scratch with these commands :

```
$ssh-keygen -t rsa 
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh $ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa 
$ cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Anybody can help me with this please ?

Comment: Have you checked the manpage of `ssh-copy-id`, how it tries to install the public key on the new host?

Comment: Yes I did! but still I keep having the same issue, I dont know what I'm missing here !

Comment: You can't use publickey auth because the key isn't there yet. You need to enable password once, after that you can disable that again.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text. **Copy-paste** the text.

Comment: Additionally (to the comment by ott), you need to specify the user for whom the key shall be added 'user@192.168.1.20'

Comment: Edit your original post instead of adding information as a comment.  As you can see, commands in comments are very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss a basic point in what you do. You need to make sure what is server, what is client and what you want to achieve.

- You generate the keys on client (your computer)
- You set up server using `sshd_config` and you want to have `authorized_keys` on the server (that IP in the image).

If you did the above, you are able to restart `sshd` server using `service sshd restart` and connect to localhost, such as `ssh localhost`.

If you want to connect somewhere else (as the above IP), you need to allow the password authentication and restart there (and not on your host). Or to transfer the key by different channel, but `ssh-copy-id` will not help with that.

Comment: You are a life saving, thanks a lot, the only thing what I missed is that I had to set Password authentication to YES in the server not in my client! Thank a lot !